# Multiple dynamic text score display. Modifying each text one after another and incrementing the score by a certain number

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have a result screen that shows bonus points and such.  I want each text field to increment one after another and also have it increment by a certain amount each frame.

Result Screen pops up.

First is the player score
check the player score, is it more than the score we want to display

if the player score is greater than the player display score by 100
increase the player display score by 100

if the player score is greater than the player display score by 10
increase the player display score by 10

else increase the player display score by 1

when finished move to the next score...and so on.

I have thought of using timers to move from one score to the next, but not being in an Event.ENTER_FRAME it only does one if then moves to the next one.  Also the if statement for incrementing the score looks ridiculous and I'm thinking there has to be a better way to do it.  I was thinking of making it a separate function but then I wouldn't know what to return, or how to return it so it looks like its increasing and not just showing the total number instantly.

If you have any questions please leave a comment.  I'll try to expand on it a little more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a new ScoreText class that inherits from TextField, and use that for each of your score text fields. On that class you could make a setTargetScore method that takes a score number, and handles the incrementation of the display number. Then it could dispatch an event when it is finished. You could listen for then events, and call the setTargetScore method on each ScoreText as you need to.

Another way, that is possibly better/easier, is to use TweenLite to tween your score number, and use its events to update the score textfield, and when its complete, move to the next one.

**EDIT***

Here is an example of using Tweenlite to tween a score variable:
[How to Tween A Variable with Flash and TweenLite](http://www.snorkl.tv/2010/09/how-to-tween-a-variable-with-flash-and-tweenlite/)

**EDIT2***

Here is an example of my first method:

First here is the ScoreText class:

```
package {
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class ScoreText extends TextField {
        public static const EVENT_SCORE_COMPLETE:String = 'scoreCompleteEvent';

        private var targetScore:Number = 0;
        private var currentScore:Number = 0;
        private const speed:Number = 0.11;

        public function ScoreText(initialScore:Number = 0) {
            currentScore = initialScore;
            updateScore();
        }

        public function setTargetScore(targetScore:Number):void {
            this.targetScore = targetScore;
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
        }

        private function enterFrameHandler(e:Event):void {
            currentScore += (targetScore - currentScore) * speed;

            if (currentScore >= targetScore -1) {
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
                dispatchEvent(new Event(EVENT_SCORE_COMPLETE));
            }

            updateScore();
        }

        private function updateScore():void {
            this.text = Math.round(currentScore).toString();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the Main class:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var st1:ScoreText;
        private var st2:ScoreText;
        private var st3:ScoreText;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            st1 = new ScoreText(0);
            st1.y = 10;
            st1.addEventListener(ScoreText.EVENT_SCORE_COMPLETE, score1Complete);
            addChild(st1);

            st2 = new ScoreText(0);
            st2.y = 60;
            st2.addEventListener(ScoreText.EVENT_SCORE_COMPLETE, score2Complete);
            addChild(st2);

            st3 = new ScoreText(0);
            st3.y = 110;
            st3.addEventListener(ScoreText.EVENT_SCORE_COMPLETE, score3Complete);
            addChild(st3);

            st1.setTargetScore(1234);
        }

        private function score1Complete(e:Event):void 
        {
            trace('score 1 finishes, start the next one!');
            st2.setTargetScore(234553);
        }

        private function score2Complete(e:Event):void 
        {
            trace('score 2 finishes, start the next one!');
            st3.setTargetScore(745);
        }

        private function score3Complete(e:Event):void 
        {
            trace('score 3 finishes, start the next one!');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could elaborate more on your first suggestion?  With an example if it's not too much trouble.

Comment: WOW thanks!  I'll give it a try as soon as I can.  As I look over it though, your creating the text fields as I already have them placed in the movieclip. Which would be best do you think?

Comment: It would be a little different if your textfields are already on the stage. You might need to wrap them in a movieclip, and set that clips class to ScoreText. Then you will have to refactor the ScoreText class to access the nested textfield, rather than extending TextField.

Comment: I did as you said and I get this error `Line 3 1152: A conflict exists with inherited definition flash.text:TextField.text in namespace public.` I made a movieclip with a text field that I already had on the stage.  I set the class/name of the script _ScoreText_ that extends _TextField_ just like you have it.